# Rational coordinates for cylinder-line intersections

Tags: geometry

Is there a 3-D coordinate system where the intersections (if any) between lines and elliptic cylinders always have rational coordinates?

Comment: Of course not. Whatever the coordinate system, you can move the line continuously and get any real value for the intersection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless you put some restrictions on the lines and cylinders, the answer is clearly no.

Any point can be expressed as the intersection of some line and some elliptic cylinder. For example, the point $(x_0, y_0, z_0)$ is an intersection of the line $x = x_0, y = y_0$ and the cylinder $x^2 + z^2 = x_0^2 + z_0^2$. Since there are uncountably many points, no scheme can represent all of them with a finite number of rational coordinates, as those can only represent countably many different objects.